# How to fix "Resource Exhausted Error"?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

While i am running the `Tensorflow` code, this error comes up.

```
 ResourceExhaustedError (see above for traceback): OOM when allocating 
  tensor with shape[518400,11]
  [[Node: gradients/loss/Sum_grad/Tile = Tile[T=DT_FLOAT, 
 Tmultiples=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]
 (gradients/loss/Sum_grad/Reshape, gradients/loss/Sum_grad/floordiv)]]
 [[Node: 
 gradients/conv_decode1/BiasAdd_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1/_495 = 
 _Recv[client_terminated=false, 
 recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", 
 send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", 
 send_device_incarnation=1,

 tensor_name="edge_2455_gradients/conv_decode1/BiasAdd_grad/tuple
 /control_dependency_1", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, )]
 _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](
```

Data set i used is CamVid. It has 367 image 360*480 and my batch-size is 5. I tried to decrease the batch size, although it is not as big as other data set i have looked, but it is not help.

I have asus laptop with geforce nvidia 940 mx , which has 2 G memory. How should i do? any suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use a Convolutional Network? How does it look like? (layers, filters, ...)
I think you use way too big numbers here. So maybe you should decrease this numbers. Other problem can be, that the images are too big, try to resize them for example from (360,480) to (240,320). On the other hand, this data set is too small. You need at least 100 times bigger data set to get a good solution. If you don't want to train a model from zero, you should use a pretrained model and finetune it.

Comment: Yes i do , i am using Convolutional Network in my code, actually i want to run  [SegNet model](https://github.com/tkuanlun350/Tensorflow-SegNet)

Comment: How much RAM has your PC?

Comment: I think RAM is 8 G and GPU has 2 G, Are you sure this is hardware fault ? and i am trying to decrease the image size @MogyorósiFerenc

Comment: It's clearly a hardware fault. Is it a pretrained model? How much RAM does it us, if you validate it on 1 image?

Comment: As you said , i decreased the size of each image to 120*160 and it is work. cross this step toward and i am so thank you